# If $G \oplus H$ is cyclic (external direct product), then $G$ and $H$ are cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that if $G \oplus H$ (external direct product) is cyclic, then $G$ and $H$ are cyclic.

If $\langle (a,b) \rangle$ = $G \oplus H$, then $|(a,b)| = |G \oplus H| = |G| |H| = lcm(|a|, |b|)$.

Then $(a,b)^{|G||H|} =((a^{|G||H|}, (b^{|H||G|}) =  ((a^{|G|})^{|H|}, (b^{|H|})^{|G|}) = (e_{G}, e_{H})$

From here I'm not sure how to use this to show that $G$ and $H$ are cyclic.

Comment: what is $\oplus$ ?

Comment: External direct product, edited for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\langle(a,b)\rangle=G\oplus H$ we will prove $\langle a \rangle= G$, to do this take $x$ in $G$, we must show there is an $n\in \mathbb Z$ with $a^n=x$. Take an $y\in H$, since $\langle (a,b)\rangle=G\oplus H$ there is an $n\in \mathbb Z$ so that $(a,b)^n=(x,y)$. We deduce $a^n=x$. So we have found the $n$ we were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If $(a,b)$ generates $G\oplus H$, what can you say about the subgroup of $G$ generated by $a$?

Answer (score 1):

$G$ and $H$ are quotients of $G\oplus H$. Quotients of cyclic groups are cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

let $(a,b)$ be generator of $G\oplus H$ consider the smallest $n$ such that $(a,b)^n=(u,1)$, $u$ generates $G$. You have $g\in G, (g,1)=(a,b)^m, m=ln$ otherwise write $m=ln+r$, $(a,b)^r=(a,b)^m(a,b)^{-ln}=(gu^{-l},1)$. This implies that $(a,b)^{ln}=(u,1)^l=(u^l,1), g=u^l$.